# Get WebClip/Device Manger Information from with an iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, airwatch, device-manager

I have an iOS device which is device managed by AirWatch. I am trying to acquire the URL for the app catalog which can be found manually under `Settings -> General -> Device Management -> Device Manager -> More Details` as depicted in the following screenshot and outlined by a red box.

[image]

Is it possible to acquire this URL from within an application (in Swift) so that I may, in effect, launch the WebClip by basically opening the URL from within the application? I know this information is probably outside the scope of the application sandbox considering even the ability to launch another application by bundle id is prohibited (unlike for Android), but I figured I would ask anyways. Unfortunately, WebClips nor the Intelligent Hub app have a URI scheme that can be used for handoff either.

Thanks in advance for any insight/help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this kind of information is only visible to Apple applications that can access the System Keychain. To get this value, the application would need to launch a URL in Safari, and have the server request this information in an HTTP request, the return a 302 redirect with the JSON embedded in the query string of the redirect URI. This is a serious amount of complexity for something that should be simple.